# How to replace date value to run on each week throughout the tsql code or any way for automation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scheduled-tasks

I have set of sql query and i am creating a multiple table based on one another. same code i am running for each week by changing the upper date through out the code. So is there any way to automate in entire sql code in MS sql server and date is change automatically?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad. Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current date using `getdate()`.  Say:

```
where convert(date, datecol) = convert(date, getdate())
```